# Settings.settings and outputing to an array

Tags: .net, settings.settings

I currently have a tab control with around 20 tabs and im looking to give each one of them a true / false value that is saved in the Settings.settings file so it can be called at the form load and only display tabs with a true value set against them.

Does anyone know how to output the contents of the Settings.settings file to an array so i can perform a for each on the saved values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach:  Create a setting in your settings file that is an `ArrayList` and store your individual tabs settings in that `ArrayList` and iterate *it*.  To me, it seems a lot simpler to iterate a single setting, rather than creating 20 (and maybe more in the future) individual settings and iterating them.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Gorilla, Will give it a shot.